# Local storage is getting updated only after refreshing the page, is there any way to update it immediately after the setItem call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the user authentication page I'm trying to set the local storage with the response token that I'm obtaining from the API call, and then navigating to the home page, where I'm trying to show the profile details if the localstorage has a value, even though the local storage is updated, I'm able to use it only after refreshing the home page, So I want to update the local storage immediately before I enter the Home page, so that there is no need to refresh, I'm not using redux so can anyone help me without the use of redux.

Thanks in advance.

**login function**

```
login(event) {
fetch('api link', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
  }),
})
  .then((Response) => Response.json())
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('result is: ', result);
    if (result.message === null) {
      this.setState({ response: 'Invalid Username' });
    } else if (result.message === 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS') {
      this.setState({ response: 'Invalid Password' });
    } else if (result.message === 'USER_DISABLED') {
      this.setState({ response: 'Not verified' });
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('ResetToken', result.token);
    }
  });
```

}

**Home page**

```
{localStorage.getItem('ResetToken') ? (
        <IconButton
          aria-controls="simple-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          <AccountCircleIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ) : null}
```

Comment: You need to pass down the state variables and setState functions using props. Your authentication component should update the appwide `isLoggedIn` state and your homepage should check for `isLoggedIn` inside a `useEffect` block and render accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

put your localStorage.getItem('ResetToken') inside a setstate to make it reactive, like

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {token: localStorage.getItem('ResetToken')};
 }

 componentDidUpdate() {
  this.setState({token:localStorage.getItem('ResetToken')})
}
{this.state.token && (
    <IconButton
      aria-controls="simple-menu"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      color="inherit"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <AccountCircleIcon />
    </IconButton>
  }
```

if no token then the component wont render if have token then it will render

Comment: Its not working, still the icon is appearing only after the reload @Neezar

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your page renders before the local storage gets updated. I found a simple asynchronous way to set and get localstorage item. You can use this as a helper function.

```
const asyncLocalStorage = {
    setItem: function (key, value) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        });
    },
    getItem: function (key) {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        });
    }
};
```